# I have to lower zoom to 69% when using the document viewer tool on GNOME to watch pdf documents with 12pt font: they are shown very large at 100% zoom

Tags: gnome

I surely did a wrong move once with the document viewer tools of GNOME on my Debian 11,

but since yesterday it opens the `pdf` documents with an unexpected growth of its content.

In the screenshot below, the normal text font size (for "*On peut y chercher une valeur précise*" sentence, for example) is 12 points.

But its display on screen is so large that **I had to put the zoom at 69.4% to make it readable confortably**.

Do you have an idea of what can have happened?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A number of tools use the screen size to size fonts and renderings.  This usually means things work out right.  Unfortunately, sometimes the display reports incorrect data, and the font sizes go all wrong.
(In my experience, TVs are more likely to be wrong than monitors.)

To determine if this is the cause, run `xdpyinfo` (probably in x11-utils) and look at the "dimension" and "resolution" lines at the start of each "screen" section.
"dimension" in millimeters should match your physical screen.
"resolution" should probably be 100 or 96 or 72, or thereabouts.

If this is the problem, there are options that can be used to override either the resolution or the physical size.

Comment: Thanks! It reports : `xdpyinfo | grep dimension` => dimensions:    2560x1440 pixels (715x402 millimeters) and `xdpyinfo | grep resolution` => resolution:    91x91 dots per inch. These numbers are looking good.

Comment: Agreed.  These numbers seem reasonable, assuming your display is actually 32.3 or 33 inches or 82cm diagonal.

Comment: @David_G Yes it's its size.

Comment: It could be a bug: I saw to issues related to this behavior, if the GNOME document viewer is `evince`? I don't know its nickname, and they aren't closed. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/1335 and https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evince/-/issues/1436 I wonder if they can be related with my trouble.